# Ignoring unknown parameters: label.x.npc, label.y.npc while using stat_fit_glance() in ggpmisc

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, p-value

I am plotting a time series data from a CSV file in R. The time series itself plots well without any error with this code:

```
data <- read.csv("SSSA_SSS.csv",
                 header = T,
                 sep = ",",
                 dec = ".")
head(data)
data$Year <- as.Date(data$ï..Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
class(data$Year)
time_plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Year, y = SSSA)) +
    geom_line(color = '#2b83e7', size = 1) + geom_point(color = "red", size =
                                                            1) +
    scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y", date_breaks = "5 year") +
    theme_bw() + stat_smooth(
        method = "lm",
        formula = y ~ x,
        size = 0.75,
        se = T,
        color = '#1ac179'
    ) + stat_poly_eq(
        face = "bold",
        parse = T,
        aes(label = ..eq.label..),
        formula = y ~ x,
        label.x.npc = 0.5,
        label.y = 0.2,
        size = 6,
        coef.digits = 4
    ) + stat_fit_glance(
    method = 'lm',
    method.args = list(formula = y ~ x),
    geom = 'text',
    aes(label = paste(
        "P-value = ", signif(..p.value.., digits = 4), sep = ""
    )),
    size = 5.7,
    label.x.npc = 0.5,
    label.y.npc = 0.9,
) + theme(
    # LABLES APPEARANCE
    plot.title = element_text(
        size = 14,
        face = "bold",
        colour = "black"
    ),
    axis.title.x = element_text(
        size = 17,
        face = "bold",
        colour = "black"
    ),
    axis.title.y = element_text(
        size = 17,
        face = "bold",
        colour = "black"
    ),
    axis.text.x = element_text(
        size = 15,
        face = "bold",
        colour = "black"
    ),
    # axis.text.y = element_text(size=12,  colour = "black"), # unbold
    axis.text.y = element_text(
        size = 15,
        face = "bold",
        colour = "black"
    ),
    # bold
    strip.text.x = element_text(
        size = 13,
        face = "bold",
        colour = "black"
    ),
    strip.text.y = element_text(
        size = 13,
        face = "bold",
        colour = "black"
    ),
    axis.line.x = element_line(color = "black", size = 1),
    axis.line.y = element_line(color = "black", size = 1),
    axis.ticks = element_line(color = "black", size = 1.2),
    panel.border = element_rect(
        colour = "black",
        fill = NA,
        size = 1
    )
print(time_plot)
```

[image] As you can see, I am able to modify the position of the equation with `stat_poly_eq()`, however "the p value" texts is not responding to the command i used :

```
stat_fit_glance(
        method = 'lm',
        method.args = list(formula = y ~ x),
        geom = 'text',
        aes(label = paste(
            "P-value = ", signif(..p.value.., digits = 4), sep = ""
        )),
        size = 5.7,
        label.x.npc = 0.5,
        label.y.npc = 0.9,
    )
```

Therefore i am unable to move the caption, even though it is overlapping with the curve as it returns with the following error:

```
1: Ignoring unknown parameters: face 
2: Ignoring unknown parameters: label.x.npc, label.y.npc
```

I understand that "face" error, but i want to manually change the position of the "p-value". I'd be grateful if someone point me out my mistake, thank you.

Comment: Checking [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggpmisc/versions/0.3.3/topics/stat_fit_glance) for `stat_fit_glance()`, it seems that `label.x.npc` and `label.y.npc` are not recognized arguments.  Using `label.x=` and `label.y=` should work.  Looks like these can receive either relative strings (`"top"`, or `"left"`, for example) or a number from 0 to 1 representing npc units.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, yes `label.x=` and `label.y=` works for me but it restricts the lables to some specific positions (e.g. top, bottom, left, right). But i want to control it manually with coordinates as i did with `stat_ploy_eqn` (e.g. label.x.npc = 0.5). Is there any way to put labels manually using coordinates in `stat_fit_glance()` . If so could you give me an example ?

Comment: According to the documentation: *"numeric with range 0..1 "normalized parent coordinates" (npc units) or character if using geom_text_npc() or geom_label_npc(). If using geom_text() or geom_label() numeric in native data units. If too short they will be recycled."*.  Since you're using a text geom, the values are in native units, so it's according to the x and y axis values (not npc units).  This means you need to supply x as a date value and y as a numeric according to your y axis.